# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku' (Python help)

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm having a lot of trouble with deploying to heroku with the python crash course material.

I have tried a few things but continually feel clueless as to why it's not working?

Seems the main error seems to be: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'

What i've tried so far:
installing pyscopg2-binary (instead of psycopg2==2.7.*)
installing django-heroku
installing gunicorn
A few other things as well.

Thanks for your help!

Here is the wsgi.py file:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'learning_log.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is in my settings.py:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'users:login'

#heroku settings
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

this is my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn learning_log.wsgi --log-file -
```

here is my requirements.txt file:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
bootstrap4==0.1.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==4.0.2
django-bootstrap4==22.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-on-heroku==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
soupsieve==2.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
static3==0.7.0
whitenoise==6.0.0
```

And here is my --tail log (sorry about the length!)

```
(ll_env) $ heroku logs --tail
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347897+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347897+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347898+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347898+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347898+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347899+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347900+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347901+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347901+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347902+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347902+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347902+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347902+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347903+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347903+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347903+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347904+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347904+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347905+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347905+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347905+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347906+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347906+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347906+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/learning_log/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347907+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347907+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347907+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347907+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347907+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347908+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 84, in __getattr__
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347908+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347908+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 71, in _setup
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347908+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347909+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 179, in __init__
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347909+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347909+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347910+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347910+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347911+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347911+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347911+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347912+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347912+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347912+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/learning_log/settings.py", line 137, in <module>
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347913+00:00 app[web.1]: import django_heroku
2022-03-13T20:49:27.347913+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348099+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-13 20:49:27 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348522+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-13 20:49:27 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348523+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348523+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348524+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348524+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348524+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348525+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348525+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348526+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348526+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348527+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348527+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348527+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348528+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348528+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348528+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348529+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348529+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348529+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348530+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348530+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348530+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348530+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348531+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348531+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/learning_log/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348531+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348532+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348532+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348532+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348533+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348533+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 84, in __getattr__
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348533+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348534+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 71, in _setup
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348534+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348534+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 179, in __init__
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348535+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348535+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348535+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348536+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348536+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348536+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348537+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348537+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348537+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348538+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/learning_log/settings.py", line 137, in <module>
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348538+00:00 app[web.1]: import django_heroku
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348538+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
2022-03-13T20:49:27.348681+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-13 20:49:27 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-03-13T20:49:27.416528+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-13 20:49:27 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-03-13T20:49:27.513734+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-13 20:49:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-03-13T20:49:27.513810+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-03-13 20:49:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2022-03-13T20:49:27.681488+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2022-03-13T20:49:27.824298+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Here is my file structure:

```
.git
.gitignore
db.sqlite3
learning_log
__init__.py
__pycache__
__init__.cpython-310.pyc
settings.cpython-310.pyc
urls.cpython-310.pyc
wsgi.cpython-310.pyc
asgi.py
settings.py
urls.py
wsgi.py
learning_logs
ll_env
manage.py
Procfile
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
staticfiles
users
```

Comment: Have you tried using [django-on-heroku](https://pypi.org/project/django-on-heroku/), which is the updated version of django-heroku?  Remove django-heroku from requirements and change settings to `import django_on_heroku` and `django_on_heroku.settings(locals())`

Comment: Yeah, I did try that - still no luck unfortunately.